# How to make an input field into a reusable field?

Tags: angularjs, forms, directive

I have this input with lots of directives on it:

```
 <input class="form-control"
                                       mobile-number
                                       limit-characters
                                       number-only
                                       dir="ltr"
                                       ng-class="{'error-form-control': vm.form.step2.phoneNumber.$invalid && (vm.form.step2.phoneNumber.$dirty || vm.form.step2.phoneNumber.$touched)}"
                                       required
                                       ng-model="vm.formData.phoneNumber"
                                       name="phoneNumber"
                                       type="text">
```

How can I make it into a reusable directive like so:

```
<phone-number ng-model="vm.formData.phoneNumber"></phone-number>
```

and how can I use angular form validation with this directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guees it will look like this

```
 app.directive('phoneNumber', function(){
       return {
          scope: {
             ngModel: '='
             classValidation: '=',
             inputName: '@'   
          },
          template: ' <input class="form-control" mobile-number limit-characters number-only dir="ltr" ng-class="classValidation" required ng-model="ngModel" name="{{inputName}}" type="text">',
          link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

          }
       }
 })
```

HTML

```
 <phone-number ng-model="vm.formData.phoneNumber" input-name="phoneNumber" class-validation="{'error-form-control': vm.form.step2.phoneNumber.$invalid && (vm.form.step2.phoneNumber.$dirty || vm.form.step2.phoneNumber.$touched)}"></phone-number>
```